# Stack of references in unsafe Rust, but ensuring that the unsafeness does not leak out of the stack?

Tags: recursion, rust, stack, lifetime, unsafe

I'm implementing some recursive code, where function instances deeper down in the call stack may need to refer to data from prior frames.  However, I only have non-mut access to those data, so I receive those data as references.  As such, I would need to keep references to those data in a stack data structure that can be accessed from the deeper instances.

To illustrate:

```
// I would like to implement this RefStack class properly, without per-item memory allocations
struct RefStack<T: ?Sized> {
    content: Vec<&T>,
}
impl<T: ?Sized> RefStack<T> {
    fn new() -> Self { Self{ content: Vec::new() } }
    fn get(&self, index: usize) -> &T { self.content[index] }
    fn len(&self) -> usize { self.content.len() }
    fn with_element<F: FnOnce(&mut Self)>(&mut self, el: &T, f: F) {
        self.content.push(el);
        f(self);
        self.content.pop();
    }
}

// This is just an example demonstrating how I would need to use the RefStack class
fn do_recursion(n: usize, node: &LinkedListNode, st: &mut RefStack<str>) {
    // get references to one or more items in the stack
    // the references should be allowed to live until the end of this function, but shouldn't prevent me from calling with_element() later
    let tmp: &str = st.get(rng.gen_range(0, st.len()));
    // do stuff with those references (println is just an example)
    println!("Item: {}", tmp);
    // recurse deeper if necessary
    if n > 0 {
        let (head, tail): (_, &LinkedListNode) = node.get_parts();
        manager.get_str(head, |s: &str| // the actual string is a local variable somewhere in the implementation details of get_str()
            st.with_element(s, |st| do_recursion(n - 1, tail, st))
        );
    }
    // do more stuff with those references (println is just an example)
    println!("Item: {}", tmp);
}

fn main() {
    do_recursion(100, list /* gotten from somewhere else */, &mut RefStack::new());
}
```

In the example above, I'm concerned about how to implement `RefStack` without any per-item memory allocations.  The occasional allocations by the `Vec` is acceptable - those are few and far in between.  The `LinkedListNode` is just an example - in practice it's some complicated graph data structure, but the same thing applies - I only have a non-mut reference to it, and the closure given to `manager.get_str()` only provides a non-mut `str`.  Note that the non-mut `str` passed into the closure may only be constructed in the `get_str()` implementation, so we cannot assume that all the `&str` have the same lifetime.

I'm fairly certain that `RefStack` can't be implemented in safe Rust without copying out the `str` into owned `String`s, so my question is how this can be done in unsafe Rust.  It feels like I might be able to get a solution such that:

- The unsafeness is confined to the implementation of `RefStack`
- The reference returned by `st.get()` should live at least as long as the current instance of the `do_recursion` function (in particular, it should be able to live past the call to `st.with_element()`, and this is logically safe since the `&T` that is returned by `st.get()` isn't referring to any memory owned by the `RefStack` anyway)

How can such a struct be implemented in (unsafe) Rust?

It feels that I could just cast the element references to pointers and store them as pointers, but I will still face difficulties expressing the requirement in the second bullet point above when casting them back to references.  Or is there a better way (or by any chance is such a struct implementable in safe Rust, or already in some library somewhere)?

Comment: It's possible that your problem is better solved with a different approach avoiding the references, but it's difficult to tell since you don't describe the actual problem you are trying to solve. That said, I think this is still a good question on its own, even in case it's not the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Do you need random access to the stack elements, or only iterative access?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I need random access to the stack elements.  The index of the element I need usually depends on some property calculated from the `head` of the current `LinkedListNode`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think there is still some unsafeness there - the variable `tmp` at line 31 may potentially be made to live longer than the frame where it was originally inserted in.

Comment: @Bernard I don't think so, since the `get()` method returns a reference with the lifetime of the `&self` reference that was passed in, not with lifetime `'a`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I played around with your code and you seem to be correct, but I still trying to wrap my head around why it works.  Could you help by adding explicit lifetime parameters for the `get()` method?

Comment: @Bernard It would simply be `fn get<'b>(&'b self, index: usize) -> &'b T`. The borrow of `self` only lives until the end of the calling function, so the returned reference can't live any longer than that.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Ah, yes, I think I finally see why now!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63414240), I implemented this slightly simpler version:

```
struct RefStack<'a, T: ?Sized + 'static> {
    content: Vec<&'a T>,
}

impl<'a, T: ?Sized + 'static> RefStack<'a, T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        RefStack {
            content: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn get(&self, index: usize) -> &'a T {
        self.content[index]
    }

    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.content.len()
    }

    fn with_element<'t, F: >(&mut self, el: &'t T, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut RefStack<'t, T>),
        'a: 't,
    {
        let mut st = RefStack {
            content: std::mem::take(&mut self.content),
        };
        st.content.push(el);
        f(&mut st);
        st.content.pop();
        self.content = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(st.content) };
    }
}
```

The only difference to rodrigo's solution is that the vector is represented as vector of references instead of pointers, so we don't need the `PhantomData` and the unsafe code to access an element.

When a new element is pushed to the stack in `with_element()`, we require that it has a shorter lifetime than the existing elements with the `a': t'` bound. We then create a new stack with the shorter lifetime, which is possible in safe code since we know the data the references in the vector are pointing to even lives for the longer lifetime `'a`. We then push the new element with lifetime `'t` to the new vector, again in safe code, and only after we removed that element again we move the vector back in it's original place. This requires unsafe code since we are *extending* the lifetime of the references in the vector from `'t` to `'a` this time. We know this is safe, since the vector is back to its original state, but the compiler doesn't know this.

I feel this version represents the intent better than rodrigo's almost identical version. The type of the vector always is "correct", in that it desribes that the elements are actually references, not raw pointers, and it always assigns the correct lifetime to the vector. And we use unsafe code exactly in the place where something potentially unsafe happens – when extending the lifetime of the references in the vector.

Comment: This is nice, but I think this version implementation has a subtle issue that _may_ still be unsound: what if `f(st)` panics? The local `&'t` reference will never not be popped! It is possible that an external `drop` implementation sees the stack and accesses the unpopped, now dangling, reference.

Comment: @rodrigo You are right, it's still unsound. I made to orthogonal changes compared to your version: (a) I changed the type of the vector to `Vec<&'a T>` and (b) I removed the code to create a new `RefStack` in `with_elemnt()`. Both of these changes can be applied independently of each other, but it turns out (b) isn't a good idea, while I still believe that (a) is – it not only makes the code shorter, it also communicates the intent better. I don't have time to fix it right now.

Comment: I fixed the problem now, making this answer even more similar to your code.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: this answer originally used traits, and it was a nightmare; Francis Gagne pointed out rightly that using an `Option` for the tail was a much better alternative, hence the answer was much simplified.*

Given the structure of your usage, with the stack in `RefStack` following the usage of the stack frames, you can simply put elements on the stack frames and build a stack from that.

The main advantage of such an approach is that it is entirely safe. You can review the [whole code here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4d1e1210ca58b4ea2e9c907bfef06976), or follow for the blow by blow description which follows.

The key is idea is to build a so-called cons-list.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Stack<'a, T> {
    element: &'a T,
    tail: Option<&'a Stack<'a, T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Stack<'a, T> {
    fn new(element: &'a T) -> Self { Stack { element, tail: None } }

    fn top(&self) -> &T { self.element }

    fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&T> {
        if index == 0 {
            Some(self.element)
        } else {
            self.tail.and_then(|tail| tail.get(index - 1))
        }
    }

    fn tail(&self) -> Option<&'a Stack<'a, T>> { self.tail }

    fn push<'b>(&'b self, element: &'b T) -> Stack<'b, T> { Stack { element, tail: Some(self) } }
}
```

A simple example of usage is:

```rust
fn immediate() {
    let (a, b, c) = (0, 1, 2);

    let root = Stack::new(&a);
    let middle = root.push(&b);
    let top = middle.push(&c);
    
    println!("{:?}", top);
}
```

Which just prints the stack, yielding:

> ```
> Stack { element: 2, tail: Some(Stack { element: 1, tail: Some(Stack { element: 0, tail: None }) }) }
> ```

And a more elaborate recursive version:

```rust
fn recursive(n: usize) {
    fn inner(n: usize, stack: &Stack<'_, i32>) {
        if n == 0 {
            print!("{:?}", stack);
            return;
        }

        let element = n as i32;
        let stacked = stack.push(&element);
        inner(n - 1, &stacked);
    }

    if n == 0 {
        println!("()");
        return;
    }

    let element = n as i32;
    let root = Stack::new(&element);
    inner(n - 1, &root);
}
```

Which prints:

> ```
> Stack { element: 1, tail: Some(Stack { element: 2, tail: Some(Stack { element: 3, tail: None }) }) }
> ```

The one downside is that `get` performance may not be so good; it has linear complexity. On the other hand, cache-wise sticking to the stack frames is pretty nice. If you mostly access the first few elements, I expect it'll be good enough.

Comment: Wouldn't I get an infinite type when I actually use this with my linked list?  (The value of `n` in my code is not known at compilation time.)

Comment: @Bernard: You would if you try to name the type. This is where the `trait` comes in, by passing `&dyn Tail<Element = str>` to `do_recursion`, it's not infinite any longer.

Comment: @MatthieuM. How would you call `push()` inside the iteration, if all you have is an `&dyn Tail`?

Comment: I suspect you might need to change the type of the `tail` in `StackElement` to a `dyn` object.  I can't really see what the `get()` method of `StackElement` can compile to at the assembly level otherwise.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: You wouldn't be able to, as it's not a method of `Tail`, but it's just a helper method you can just do without it.

Comment: @Bernard: Goodness, I indeed hit issues with `dyn` I hadn't thought about as soon as I tried the recursive case; update incoming.

Comment: I find the idea of putting the data onto the stack itself to be quite novel and interesting.  It feels quite like an intrusive linked list in some way.  For my problem, the number of levels of recursion is dependent on the data being processed, and usually should not be more than 20 to 40.  I'm still somewhat more inclined to SvenMarnach's solution though - the constant-time guarantees there are nice, and the RefStack object and the Vec data in it should both be quite hot in the cache so I think it would also be quite fast.

Comment: @Bernard: I like Sven's solution too, I just wish it wasn't `unsafe`. It is quite likely to be faster, due to O(1) access. I don't mind the _inner_ `unsafe` so much -- it's pretty common in collections -- it's more the fact that unsafety leaks to the user which annoys me. My mind keeps screaming that there ought to be a better way...

Comment: [You don't need a trait if you're OK with using `Option` instead.](https://github.com/racer-rust/racer/pull/698/files)

Comment: @FrancisGagné: _groan_! Well, I'll rewrite this little puppy then...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh yes the `Option` solution looks much neater!  I'm quite sure this also would be more efficient than the Traits because the indirect function call was removed.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, quite likely. It still suffers from O(n) `get` unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I think storing raw pointer is the way to go. You need a `PhantomData` to store the lifetime and get proper covariance:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct RefStack<'a, T: ?Sized> {
    content: Vec<*const T>,
    _pd: PhantomData<&'a T>,
}

impl<'a, T: ?Sized> RefStack<'a, T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        RefStack {
            content: Vec::new(),_pd: PhantomData
        }
    }
    fn get(&self, index: usize) -> &'a T {
        unsafe { &*self.content[index] }
    }
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.content.len()
    }
    fn with_element<'t, F: FnOnce(&mut RefStack<'t, T>)>(&mut self, el: &'t T, f: F)
        where 'a: 't,
    {
        self.content.push(el);
        let mut tmp = RefStack {
            content: std::mem::take(&mut self.content),
            _pd: PhantomData,
        };
        f(&mut tmp);
        self.content = tmp.content;
        self.content.pop();
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e16551c9ff6677a99c277e73f793ddf))

The only `unsafe` code is in converting the pointer back into a reference.

The tricky part is getting the `with_element` right. I think that the `were 'a: 't` is implicit, because the whole `impl` depends on it (but better safe than sorry).

The last problem is how to convert a `RefStack<'a, T>` into a `RefStack<'t, T>`. I'm pretty sure I could just `std::transmute` it. But that would an extra `unsafe` to pay attention to, and creating a new temporary stack one is quite trivial.

#### About the `'t` lifetime

You may think that this `'t` lifetime is not actually needed, but not adding it may cause subtle unsoundness, as the callback could call `get()` and get values with a lifetime `'a` that is actually longer than the inserted value.

For example this code should not compile. With the `'t` it correctly fails, but without it it compiles and causes undefined behavior:

```
fn breaking<'a, 's, 'x>(st: &'s mut RefStack<'a, i32>, v: &'x mut Vec<&'a i32>) {
    v.push(st.get(0));
}
fn main() {
    let mut st = RefStack::<i32>::new();
    let mut y = Vec::new();
    {
        let i = 42;
        st.with_element(&i, |stack| breaking(stack, &mut y));
    }
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

#### About `panic!`.

When doing these kind of unsafe things, particularly when you are calling user code, as we are doing now in `with_element`, we have to consider what would happen if it panics. In the OP code, the last object will *not* be popped, and when the stack is unwound, any `drop` implementation could see the now dangling reference. My code is ok in case of panics because, if `f(&mut tmp);` the dangling references die in the local temporary `tmp` while `self.content` is empty.

Comment: This has the same problem as my implementation. You can break this by storing another reference to the `RefStack` inside the closure, and using this to sneak out a value that was added in an inner frame with the lifetime of the outer frame. See my answer for an example.

Comment: Oh, wait, maybe that doesn't work here, since `with_element()` is taking `self` by mutable reference, so we can't have any other references to the stack stored anywhere.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Yes, that is part of the idea. This and the separated `'a` and `'t` lifetimes. I feel that without the `'t` I should be able to break it, but I don't know how...

Comment: Without the `'t` it's trivial to break, since `get()` will return a reference with a lifetime that's potentially longer than the item it points to, so you can store that in some other place with a longer lifetime.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Yes, not so trivial to write because closures always have their lifetimes elided, and they keep on being resolved wrongly. I managed to break it with a quite convoluted example. If you can write a simpler one, feel free to edit or comment.

Comment: I think I might be missing something obvious here, but what is the problem with covariance if we didn't have the `PhantomData`?  Isn't `Vec<*const T>` already covariant to `T`?

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, `*const T` is covariant to `T`, but not not `'a`. Since `RefStack` behaves _as if_ it contains a bunch of `&'a T` I guess it should be covariant to the lifetime too. And you need a `PhantomData` anyway to hold the lifetime, so it's just natural to me to write `PhantomData<&'a T>`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: But covariance is not only for the implementation, the user may need it for other totally unrelated reasons. Anyway, since I would have to go out of my way to not having it... there it is. Your new solution is cool, arguably simpler than mine, but every time I see `mem::transmute` I get a bit _uneasy_, even more when there are `&mut` around...

Comment: I've posted my version as a separate answer, so I'm cleaning up a few comments here.

Comment: The compiler lets you write that code without `'t` because you're not actually using the variance that is there. [This playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?edition=2018&gist=6927a23edfdec7bd2623d61969a5d5bf) showcases creating the temporary stack with the same lifetime parameter and using variance to use it as a parameter to `f` inside `with_element`; with the `where` clause commented out, the compiler rightfully complains (admittedly not as helpfully as I would like). We could just use `self` as parameter, but this would break in case of panics, which you should describe in the answer btw.

Comment: Self is actually invariant if behind a mutable reference, so the last sentence of my previous comment is not entirely correct. If your comment about the possibility of using `transmute` was about transmuting the `self` reference itself, there's still the issue of panics, so that would have to be adressed. By not wanting to use `transmute` you might have inadvertently bypassed that panic issue :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Where is your version of this solution?  It seemed to look quite good when I read it yesterday.

Comment: @JakubDąbek: I've added a note about the panic, thanks for the tip. And yes, I inadvertently avoided the panic issue by consciously avoiding `transmute`.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware that it's possible to not terminate after a panic happens.  Would [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5984d63ced13e7e894f483a73e3ed839) version with `transmute` be exception-safe too?  This might be purely theoretical, but maybe the user would expect all the RefStack references to point to the same real object.  EDIT: Nevermind, your solution might even be more efficient if the compiler inlines enough to elide the double dereferencing.

Comment: @Bernard: I think your version with the scope guard trick is safe. I didn't understand your theoretical point about the same real object, though. About the efficiency, I think it is mostly negligible any way.

Comment: @bernard I deleted the answer because rodrigo pointed out a problem with it, and I didn't have time to fix it on Friday. I fixed and reinstated it now, but it's even more similar to this answer now, and only a slight improvement.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: A different answer; with a different trade-off.*

Compared to my other answer, this answer presents a solution that is:

- **unsafe**: it's encapsulated, but subtle.
- simpler to use.
- simpler code, likely faster.

The idea is to *still* use the stack to bind the lifetimes of the references, yet storing all lifetimes in a single `Vec` for O(1) random access. So we're building a stack on the stack, but not storing the references themselves on the stack. Alright?

The full code [is available here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=81a67b7c8a86f5a2ad9ac94dcf693b13).

The stack itself is very easily defined:

```rust
struct StackRoot<T: ?Sized>(Vec<*const T>);

struct Stack<'a, T: ?Sized>{
    len: usize,
    stack: &'a mut Vec<*const T>,
}

impl<T: ?Sized> StackRoot<T> {
    fn new() -> Self { Self(vec!()) }

    fn stack(&mut self) -> Stack<'_, T> { Stack { len: 0, stack: &mut self.0 } }
}
```

The implementation of `Stack` is trickier, as always when `unsafe` is involved:

```rust
impl<'a, T: ?Sized> Stack<'a, T> {
    fn len(&self) -> usize { self.len }

    fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&'a T> {
        if index < self.len {
            //  Safety:
            //  -   Index is bounds as per above branch.
            //  -   Lifetime of reference is guaranteed to be at least 'a (see push).
            Some(unsafe { &**self.stack.get_unchecked(index) })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    fn push<'b>(&'b mut self, element: &'b T) -> Stack<'b, T>
        where
            'a: 'b
    {
        //  Stacks could have been built and forgotten, resulting in `self.stack`
        //  containing references to further elements, so that the newly pushed
        //  element would not be at index `self.len`, as expected.
        //
        //  Note that on top of being functionally important, it's also a safety
        //  requirement: `self` should never be able to access elements that are
        //  not guaranteed to have a lifetime longer than `'a`.
        self.stack.truncate(self.len);

        self.stack.push(element as *const _);
        Stack { len: self.len + 1, stack: &mut *self.stack }
    }
}

impl<'a, T: ?Sized> Drop for Stack<'a, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.stack.truncate(self.len);
    }
}
```

Do note the `unsafe` here; the invariant is that `'a` parameter is *always* stricter that the lifetimes of the elements pushed into the stack *so far*.

By refusing to access elements pushed by other members, we thus guarantee that the lifetime of the returned reference is valid.

It does require a generic definition of `do_recursion`, however generic lifetime parameters are erased at code generation, so there's no code bloat involved:

```rust
fn do_recursion<'a, 'b>(nodes: &[&'a str], stack: &mut Stack<'b, str>) 
    where
        'a: 'b
{
    let tmp: &str = stack.get(stack.len() - 1).expect("Not empty");
    println!("{:?}", tmp);

    if let [head, tail @ ..] = nodes {
        let mut new = stack.push(head);
        do_recursion(tail, &mut new);
    }
}
```

A simple `main` to show it off:

```rust
fn main() {
    let nodes = ["Hello", ",", "World", "!"];
    let mut root = StackRoot::new();
    let mut stack = root.stack();
    let mut stack = stack.push(nodes[0]);

    do_recursion(&nodes[1..], &mut stack);
}
```

Resulting in:

> ```
> "Hello"
> ","
> "World"
> "!"
> ```

Comment: How could stacks be built and forgotten?  It seems to me that the `Drop` impl for `Stack` should already have handled it.

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully to get a `with_element()` version working [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b50b89dae5b5bf5026b398dcd72852a1).  It appears that I can't convince the compiler that the parameter of `f` won't live past the function invocation.  Is there some way to get `with_element()` to work?

Comment: @Bernard: literally `std::mem::forget` :)

Comment: @Bernard: Indeed, this `with_element` is annoying -- and the compiler is not really helping. Do you really need it though? It's only doing `{ let mut new = stack.push(element); do_recursion(tail, &mut new); }`.

Comment: How would I actually use `std::mem::forget`?  This does not seem to work: `let mut tmp = Stack { len: self.len + 1, stack: &mut *self.stack };  f(&mut tmp);  std::mem::forget(tmp);`

Comment: @Bernard: I am not sure how `mem::forget` could be used, it's just that since in Rust it's considered safe to leak (such as with `mem::forget`) safety should never rely on `Drop` being executed.

Comment: @Bernard: Here is a version with `with_element` [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=077414a559564c0351db8985471f68c7); figuring out the lifetimes was a bit tricky indeed.

Comment: It isn't really necessary to use `with_element`, but it feels neater than doing it this way.  Also, this way requires you to write truncate twice, which seems fairly surprising to me.